Is $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ an integrally closed domain?
One can prove that a UFD must be an integrally closed domain, and from this questionenter link description here we can see $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ is not a UFD. So is $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ an integrally closed domain? I guess it is true but have not given a prove so far. Could anyone give a help?

The ring is isomorphic $\Bbb C[u^2,uv,v^2]$, and $\Bbb C[u^2,uv,v^2]\subseteq \Bbb C[u,v]$ is an integral etension.

@DietrichBurde I knew it but don't knew how to use it.

See the duplicate, how to use it.

@DietrichBurde thanks
